# Convert Powershell data clean up code to Python Code

Tags: python, powershell, csv

I would like to convert the Powershell script below to Python code.

- Here is the objective of this code.

- The code takes in a comma delimited filename and file extension.
- The code below exports file as a pipe delimited file
- Then it removes commas that exists within the data
- Finally it also removes the double quotes used to qualify the data.

This results in the final file being pipe delimited with no double quotes or commas in the data. In doing this work I used this order because if you try to just replace double quotes and commas before establishing pipes the columns and data would break.

```
Param([string]$RootString,  [string]$Ext)   

$OrgFile = $RootString
$NewFile = $RootString.replace($Ext,"out")

Import-Csv $OrgFile -Encoding UTF8 | Export-Csv tempfile.csv -Delimiter "|" -NoTypeInformation
(Get-Content tempfile.csv).Replace(",","").Replace('"',"") | Out-File $NewFile -Encoding UTF8

Copy-Item -Force $NewFile $OrgFile
Remove-Item –path $NewFile -Force
```

I got dinged a point for this but. Did not see a point in posting bad code that does not work. Here is my version of non working code.

```
for index in range(len(dfcsv)):
    filename = dfcsv['csvpath'].iloc[index]
    print(filename)
    print(i)
    with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
        text = f.read()
        print(datetime.now())
        text = re.sub('","', '|', text)
        print(datetime.now())
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(text)
        f.truncate()
        i = i + 1
```

Issues with this code is the method of find and replace. This was creating extra column in the beginning due to double quote. Then sometimes extra column at the end since sometimes there was a double quote at the end. This caused data from different rows to merge together. I didn't post this part as I didn't think it was necessary for my objective. More relevant seemed to put working code to create a better idea of objective. Here is the non working code.

Comment: What's your problem? Do you need someone to code it for you?

Comment: Have not been able to this  work in python. I an not as versed in python.

Comment: in an effort to avoid confusion @thomas i did not post the python code I wrote because it does not work and i think some who knows more python than me will be able to write this more elegantly. Here is my python version of this code

Answer (score 0):

Seem no one here wanted to answer question so I found solution else where. Here is the link for anyone needing to convert comma file to pipe delimited:
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29188372/How-can-I-Convert-Powershell-data-clean-up-code-to-Python-Code.html